# Type mismatch error on checking presence of element in a Set in Spark Scala API

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have defined following function written in Scala, for finding out whether particular type of nodes(Project,Filter) is contained in a given set or not:

```
private val operators = Set(Project.getClass,Filter.getClass)    
def containsNode(plan: Seq[LogicalPlan]):Boolean=
    {
     for(p<- plan)
       {
         if(operators.contains(p.getClass))
           true
       }
  false
}
```

When running the code I am getting the following error for the above function:

> Error:(182, 36) type mismatch;
> found   : Class[T(in value $anonfun)] where type T(in value $anonfun) <: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan
>
> required: Class[_ >: T(in value operators) with T <: Serializable]
>
> ```
> if(operators .contains(p.getClass))
> ```

I thought `p.getClass` would give same type of value that set `operators` expect. But it doesn't seem like it. I am new to Scala and Spark, so I am not sure what exactly is going on here. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

In this case the problem is too precise type inference, you can fix it by explicitly saying `operators` is a set of any classes:

```
private val operators = Set[Class[_]](Project.getClass,Filter.getClass)
```

Though a second problem is that just using `true` like that won't return it as you probably intend. You can explicitly write `return true` but better to use `exists` which already contains the desired logic:

```
def containsNode(plan: Seq[LogicalPlan]): Boolean =
    plan.exists(p => operators.contains(p.getClass))
```

EDIT: a third possible problem is that `Project` in `Project.getClass` is not the class, but its companion object, you probably want `classOf[Project]` instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "too precise type inference"?

Comment: The common supertype of `Project.getClass` and `Filter.getClass` is not `Class[_]` because `Project` and `Filter` have a common supertype.